# Errors appearing after updating the Firebase auth package -- Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, podfile

I added the firebase auth package then  got an error in the ios podfile

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
In Podfile:
Firebase/Auth

```
firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Auth (~> 6.3)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/Environment":
In Podfile:
firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Auth (~> 6.3) was resolved to 6.3.0, which depends on
FirebaseAuth (~> 6.1.2) was resolved to 6.1.2, which depends on
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)

```
google_mlkit_face_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitFaceDetection (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitCommon (~> 7.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
        GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.0) was resolved to 9.1.2, which depends on
          GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.2)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitCommon":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
GoogleMLKit/DigitalInkRecognition (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
MLKitDigitalInkRecognition (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
MLKitMDD (~> 4.1) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
MLKitCommon (~> 8.0)

```
google_mlkit_face_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitCommon (~> 7.0.0)

google_mlkit_face_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitFaceDetection (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitCommon (~> 7.0)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitLanguageID":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_language_id (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_language_id/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
GoogleMLKit/LanguageID (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
MLKitLanguageID (~> 3.1.0)

```
google_mlkit_smart_reply (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_smart_reply/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/SmartReply (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitSmartReply (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitLanguageID (~> 3.1)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitTextRecognitionCommon":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_text_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_text_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
MLKitTextRecognition (~> 1.4.0-beta5) was resolved to 1.4.0-beta5, which depends on
MLKitTextRecognitionCommon (= 1.0.0-beta5)

```
google_mlkit_text_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_text_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/TextRecognitionJapanese (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitTextRecognitionJapanese (~> 1.0.0-beta5) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta6, which depends on
      MLKitTextRecognitionCommon (= 1.0.0-beta6)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitVision":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_commons (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_commons/ios`) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
MLKitVision

```
google_mlkit_face_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_face_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitFaceDetection (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitVision (~> 4.1)

google_mlkit_object_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_object_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetectionCustom (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitObjectDetectionCustom (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      MLKitObjectDetectionCommon (~> 4.1) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
        MLKitVision (~> 4.2)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitXenoCommon":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_pose_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_pose_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
GoogleMLKit/PoseDetection (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
MLKitPoseDetection (~> 1.0.0-beta9) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta10, which depends on
MLKitXenoCommon (= 1.0.0-beta10)

```
google_mlkit_pose_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_pose_detection/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
    MLKitPoseDetectionAccurate (~> 1.0.0-beta9) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta9, which depends on
      MLKitXenoCommon (= 1.0.0-beta9)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists, I recommend deleting the Podfile.lock file from your iOS repository and in the repo's terminal, type in:

```
cd iOS
pod deintegrate
pod install --repo-update
```

This shall update all your cocoa pods to the latest possible version. If you do that and you keep getting the same error, I'd recommend looking into the version of your dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file and updating all those that are outdated as well.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal do

```
cd ios
pod install
```